# Why is Shukracharya connected with Venus & Brihaspati with Jupiter?

Tags: navagraha, brihaspati, shukracharya

Of the navagriha some of the connections are quite apparent like those of Surya and Chandra with the star and satellite respectively. Shani is connected to Saturn and Budh to mercury & it is believable since they are all celestial bodies. But why is Brihaspati connected with Jupiter or Shukra with Venus? Is there any story behind it?

Comment: Why is it 'apparent' ? If you didn't know english and had not heard of the name 'jupiter', you would only know it by the name of Guru (aka brihaspati), and you won't have any question or confusion of why it's connected. Whatever 'connection' you find believable (Saturn-Shani), it is the same connection between Venus-Shukra

Comment: I think you didn't get what I meant. Surya is clearly equated in the scriptures as thr Sun and Soma is told to be the overlord of Moon in many stories. That is not the case with brihaspati and Shukracharya who are always shown residing with their disciples Devas or Asuras that is why the query.